# How can I use and debug an iOS version a simulator doesn't exist for?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios8, simulator

I'm in the midst of squashing bugs for my App in development, and I've stumbled across a problem when it comes to addressing a crash occurring on iOS 8.0.2

The problem is that I can't actually test (On the simulator) for iOS 8.0.2 as the earliest version of iOS 8 I can use is 8.1

[image]

I am not supporting iOS 7, but did go back and try to see if I could catch the bug there as described by the tester who reported the crash. It did not occur no matter what I did, so I assume it must occur when running iOS 8 only.

I'm not sure how to address this problem. I would like to submit my App for review, but if I cannot eliminate this crash I will be rejected. Yet I can't test for it either. I've been waiting a day+ now for any crash report to come back from Test-Flight, but none have shown yet. It could take around three days for that to happen.

Can anyone assist me in finding another way or workaround to be able to test for this crash?

Comment: If the crash only happens on iOS 8.0.x (or if it's simply very intermittent) you'll have no problems getting Apple to approve it. They're only going to reject a build if it crashes in front of them. (Of course, whether you want to ship with a known crash and risk annoying your users is a different question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download and install [Xcode 6](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_6.0.1/xcode_6.0.1.dmg) ([Xcode 6.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1.1/xcode_6.1.1.dmg) might also have the iOS 8.0 simulator) as that'll have the iOS 8 SDK and simulators (you'll have to be signed in to your Apple developer account to access those links otherwise pick from the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)).

The problem you'll then have with that though, is that you'll be compiling your code against a different SDK. But its worth a try!

Its also difficult to get specific 8.0.X versions of the simulators as they only really have the minor version release (8.X) available as opposed to the bug fix releases.

Obviously the only guaranteed way to reproduce the issue is on a 8.0.2 device.

Comment: Might you know a good guide to installing Xcode 6 that is not outdated? I would like to try this solution but am finding lots of outdated guides for installing multiple versions of Xcode.

Comment: Just download the `dmg`, open it and drag it into your applications folder. It'll say there is already an item with the name Xcode, but chose the keep both option, and then open the version you want.

Comment: Thank you. I have used the Simulator with iOS 8.0, and been unable to find the bug. I will have to conclude it is impossible to fix without iOS 8.0.2. However, your solution did work to a certain extent.

Comment: Ah sorry to hear that. What about changing the deployment target to 8.1 and then you'll never see the bug again :D

Comment: I believe that is the best solution.